# Object or embed is not working in MVC

Tags: html, asp.net-mvc, pdf, html-object

I am trying to show PDF into view using `<embed>` or `<object>` in MVC view page.

**View.cshtml**

```
<object data="@Server.MapPath(ViewBag.FileName)"  type="application/pdf" >
If you are unable to view file, you can download from
</object>
```

When I view page, I am getting PDF path correctly but PDF is not visible into page.
 [image]

My same code is working into simple HTML file.

**Path:**
[image]

Comment: What is the size/position of the `object` element? Are you sure the path exists?

Comment: try to add width/height to 100%.

Comment: I've updated path and given width and height as well

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As per the documentation at https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/object, the `data` attribute of an `<object>` tag must be:

> The address of the resource as a **valid URL**.

(the bold is mine, to make the point here).

In other words, you need to specify a URL pointing at the PDF, not a file path. The browser has no access to the server's disk, so it cannot read directly from it. All it can do is make a HTTP request to a URL to get the document.

So it might be something like this:

```
<object data="documents/@ViewBag.FileName"  type="application/pdf" >
```

but of course exactly what you use depends on where you place the document, and exactly what you have put into ViewBag.Filename already.

Note that the `App_Data` folder in an MVC application is not accessible from the web (and it's not desirable to make it accessible, since it contains things like database files), so you'll have to place the PDF somewhere else more suitable.

Comment: Ok. so I moved pdf to content folder and it is working. but no luck with App_data folder.

Comment: @UbiquitousDevelopers that's great. I assume you changed to using a URL as well instead of path? Like I said in the answer, it's not intended to work with the App_Data folder, so it's not really a question of luck, it's designed that way for security so that the database files are not exposed to the internet directly.

Comment: ok. got your point. so App_Data folder is used to secure files and not to expose to outside world. isn't it?

Answer (score -3):

Can you not do a Method that returns a FileContentResult that reads the file and just display the content on the frontend?

And add a Click here to download to be able to download it if that is necessary.

Cheeres!

Comment: The are trying to embed the PDF, not download it.

Comment: And add a Click here to download to be able to download it if that is necessary

while i add if necessary, the FileContent result can display the PDF contents, and as it stands in the first code example "If you cant view you can download it" so I just added it, cause of that comment.

Comment: *the FileContent result can display the PDF contents* No, the question being asked is why the embed isn't working, they're not looking for a different solution. While it might work, you should have suggested it as a comment, not an answer.

Comment: Thanks @DavidG will do that next time and not publish as an answer! Thanks!

Comment: By the way, the perfect answer here would be to first answer OPs question, and then maybe suggest what you have here. The best of both worlds.

Comment: Appreciate the feedback! :)